Back-assign elements to MainLayout component from Child page in Blazor
Taking the standard structure of a blazor wasm project as an example, with the MainLayout component and razor pages denoted by the @page directive that is, basically I would need to render an element within the MainLayout component, the one who is calling the @Body directive, that is defined (as html) in another component which is a @page
Reason behind this is that I wish I could reserve a particular "spot" in the layout defined in the MainLayout for the pages to consume it and "inject" their stuff in there.
Something like you do with children RenderFragments but in the opposite direction.
Is it even possible?

I think Blazor sections provides the functionality you're looking for.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0

SectionOutlets!! So dumb of me totally forgot about them! Thank you so much that will totally do! Please, if you post it as an answer I’ll mark it as accepted!

I think Blazor sections provides the functionality you're looking for.
See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Thank you so much. That will totally serve me well.
